# R - Use a value in a variable to conditionally select multiple values from other variables

Tags: r

I am trying to compare colours in 3D CIELuv colourspace, and I want to identify the L, U, and V values for the colour that is closest to my primary colour of interest. I have calculated the Euclidean distance between each source colour (represented by the three coordinates, L, U, and V, for each colour) and the primary colour (for which I also have the LUV coordinates, not shown for space). The distances between each colour and the primary colour are stored in the three `DistCol` variables. I then found the smallest of these distances using `df$Min.Dist <- colnames(df[c(10:12)])[unlist(apply(df[c(10:12)], 1, which.min))]`. Example:

```
  Colour1L Colour1U Colour1V Colour2L Colour2U Colour2V Colour3L Colour3U Colour3V DistCol1 DistCol2 DistCol3 Min.Dist
1     25.5      9.0    -54.5     98.8      0.0     -1.6     63.9     55.0     60.2     25.4     82.1    137.8 DistCol1
2      8.7     14.8      5.6     41.7    133.2     27.6     41.7    133.2     27.6    144.2     58.3    133.3 DistCol2
3     83.2     24.7    -42.7     21.6     -0.4      0.8     83.2     24.7    -42.7     12.1    170.6    102.3 DistCol1
4     55.0    -49.8     62.5     99.2      0.1     -1.8     55.0    -49.8     62.5    213.7    103.4     67.7 DistCol3
```

I want to use the `Min.Dist` variable (or any other method really, if there's a better way!) to conditionally select all three L, u, and v values for whichever colour is the closest. That is, in the first row, `Min.Dist` is `DistCol1`, so the three `Source` values would all come from the three `Colour1` columns. My final output would ideally look like:

```
  Colour1L Colour1U Colour1V Colour2L Colour2U Colour2V Colour3L Colour3U Colour3V DistCol1 DistCol2 DistCol3 Min.Dist SourceL SourceU SourceV
1     25.5      9.0    -54.5     98.8      0.0     -1.6     63.9     55.0     60.2     25.4     82.1    137.8 DistCol1    25.5     9.0   -54.5
2      8.7     14.8      5.6     41.7    133.2     27.6     41.7    133.2     27.6    144.2     58.3    133.3 DistCol2    41.7   133.2    27.6
3     83.2     24.7    -42.7     21.6     -0.4      0.8     83.2     24.7    -42.7     12.1    170.6    102.3 DistCol1    83.2    24.7   -42.7
4     55.0    -49.8     62.5     99.2      0.1     -1.8     55.0    -49.8     62.5    213.7    103.4     67.7 DistCol3    55.0   -49.8    62.5
```

I have previously obtained a similar result using a long nested `ifelse` expression for each of the L, U, and V dimensions e.g. `df$SourceL <- ifelse(df$Min.Dist =="DistCol1", Colour1L, ifelse(df$Min.Dist == "DistCol2", Colour2L, ifelse(...` but I'm dealing with 8-10 colours in my real data and this is extremely tedious and prone to error.

I apologise if this question has already been answered elsewhere, and would very much appreciate any advice or direction to a resource for this.  Thank you as well to everyone who answers questions on this forum - your advice has been invaluable for solving many R problems over the past months!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this in a non-vectorized way with base R:

1. rebuilding your data.frame:

   ```
   df <- data.frame(c(25.5,8.7,83.2,55),c(9,14.8,24.7,-49.8),c(-54.5,5.6,-42.7,62.5), c(98.8,41.7,21.6,99.2),c(0,133.2,-0.4,0.1),c(-1.6,27.6,0.8,-1.8),c(63.9,41.7,83.2,55),c(55,133.2,24.7,-49.8),c(60.2,27.6,-42.7,62.5),c(25.4,144.2,12.1,213.7),c(82.1,58.3,170.6,103.4),c(137.8,133.3,102.3,67.7),c("DistCol1","DistCol2","DistCol1","DistCol3"))
   colnames(df) <- c("Colour1L", "Colour1U", "Colour1V", "Colour2L", "Colour2U",  "Colour2V", "Colour3L", "Colour3U", "Colour3V", "DistCol1", "DistCol2", "DistCol3", "Min.Dist")
   ```
2. Looping over rows

   ```
   for (i in 1:length(df$Colour1L)) {
       df$SourceL[i] <- df[[paste0("Colour",substr(df$Min.Dist,8,8)[i],"L")]][i] 
       df$SourceU[i] <- df[[paste0("Colour",substr(df$Min.Dist,8,8)[i],"U")]][i] 
       df$SourceV[i] <- df[[paste0("Colour",substr(df$Min.Dist,8,8)[i],"V")]][i] 
      }
   ```